# System monitor indicator does not start after latest update of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: indicator, monitor, system

System monitor indicator does not start anymore after the latest updates for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
I installed the app using this PPA (http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/indicator-sysmonitor/ubuntu)

each time i attempt to open the application, i receive the following error message;

> **The application System Monitor Indicator has closed unexpectedly.**
> **ExecutablePath :** /usr/lib/indicator-sysmonitor/indicator-sysmonitor
> **Package :** indicator-sysmonitor 0.8.1-1
> **ProblemType :** Crash
> **Title :** indicator-sysmonitor crashed with importError in find_module: cannot import name Appindicator3, introspection typelib not found
> **Architecture :** amd64
> **currentDesktop :** Unity
> **Distrorelease :** Ubuntu 16.04

The application was working fine until i recently used Software updater to update all my ubuntu programs. I do not know how to fix this problem.

any help would be greatly appreciated.
thank you

Comment: Try `sudo apt install --reinstall indicator-sysmonitor`.

Comment: You might also file a bug report at the PPA

Answer (score 1):

reinstalling the app did not help. However I sent a bug report to the PPA and they responded by saying i was missing the following package from the install;  **gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1**

so i installed it `apt-get install gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1` , restarted Ubuntu, and everything seems to be working fine now.

thanks for help